# Perl Scraping Product Id using URL

Tags: perl, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Can I use a Perl script in conjunction with a product ID to scrape for active product pages by increasing the product id by "1" and reporting back when ID's are found?

The form URL action takes the look of:

URL/checkout/cart/ajaxadd/uenc/product/75668/

The 75668 in the above URL is the product ID that I would like to run through a loop and count up, reporting back ID's as they are found.

Is there a certain resource or any direction that I can be pointed to?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that. Look at `LWP` or `WWW::Mechanize`, but you would very likely be contravening the site's terms and conditions

Furthermore, if you are trying every product ID from zero up to 75668, and each internet transaction takes (a very optimistic) three seconds, then it will take you nearly three days. And I assume you don't want to stop at 75668

Comment: Thank you Borodin. I will look into mechanize and will be conscious of the sites terms as well as how many pages are being accessed.